# Pointing a domain to a different host?

Tags: dns

I'm trying to point a domain name hosted at namesco to a different server, but the people who own the server have said not to change the nameservers as it will break the emails they have. They have said to point to a server name host.therename.com.

I have tried pointing the www CNAME to host.therename.com but it has not changed (48 hours ago), am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an "A" record to your domain, and point that to the IP address of the server that you want to host the website on.

You can leave the CNAME on the "www" subdomain, so people typing in yourdomain.com and www.yourdomain.com will end up at your server.

Comment: Thanks I was not given an IP address so I'll try and get that now.